# Downloading google app engine database (java project)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bulkloader

I would download the google app engine datastore. I'm following several guides, but none of those helps me.
My web.xml file is setted correctly for the use of remote_api.
I have installed the python sdk and relative google appengine launcher.

I run these instructions in ../Google/google_appengine:

```
bulkloader.py --dump --application=appID --url=http://appID.appspot.com/remote_api --filename=x.dump
```

The result is: "Have 11 entities, 0 previusly transferred"; "11 entities transferred in .. seconds"

But I don't find this file, so I don't know if the download is occurred. 
I have to create the .dump file previously or it is created automatically.
I have the same problem also with the "--download_data" command.

Answer (score 0):

It works if change the --filename path (where it saves the .dump file).
Probably ../Google/google_appengine folder is protected.